# About the log return in the Black&Scholes model

Tags: black-scholes, log-returns

I'm currently studying the Black&Scholes model and I'm not sure about the following thing: the log return, say r, doesn't evolve in time? I mean, dr/dt = 0, its derivative is zero? Does only its average evolve in time, that is, d average(r)/dt = something? Thank you.

Comment: In the classic model, r is assumed to be constant, as well explained in the answer below. In terms of dynamics, it features as a a constant coefficient in the evolution of the bank account: $dB_t=r B_t$, and through this (combined with the magic of the valuation formula) it makes its way to the drift of the stock price evolution equation.

Comment: Ismael, if you like Bob's (or mine) answer below, could you pls click on the "tick mark" next to one of the answers so that this question can be marked as "complete"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me try to answer. In the Black-Scholes model, we have the following dynamics for a stock Price $S_t$:

$$S(t)=S(0)+\int^{t}_{0}r S(h)dh+\int^{t}_{0}\sigma S(h)dW(h)$$

The short-hand notation for the above would be:

$$dS_t= r S_t dt+\sigma S_tdW_t$$

The two equations are the same thing (just two different notations) and the solution to both is the log-normal process:

$$S_t = S_0exp{(rt+0.5\sigma^2t+ \sigma W(t)})$$

The **log-return** is defined as $ln\left(\frac{S_t}{S_0}\right)$, so we can easily see that:

$$ln\left(\frac{S_t}{S_0}\right)=rt+0.5\sigma^2t+ \sigma W(t)$$

You can see that the log-return is *Normally* distributed with mean $=rt+0.5\sigma^2t$ and standard deviation $=\sigma \sqrt(t)$ (why? Because **by definition** $\sigma W(t)$ is normally distributed with mean zero and standard deviation equal to $\sigma \sqrt(t)$) .

So the log-return itself evolves in time: it is a stochastic process that is normally distributed around its (time-dependent) mean and it has a (time-dependent) standard deviation. If you plot the log-return on x-y axes, with y being time and x being the log-return, you can picture it as a straight line with slope $rt$ where the Normal distribution of the log-return is tangentially centered on this straight line. As time goes on, the standard deviation of this Normal distribution around the line gets wider and wider.

Answer (score 2):

The risk-free rate is assumed to be constant, see for example [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black%E2%80%93Scholes_model#Fundamental_hypotheses):

> (riskless rate) The rate of return on the riskless asset is constant and thus called the risk-free interest rate.

Under the risk-neutral measure (where pricing using the Black-Scholes formula happens), the return on the stock is equal to the risk-free rate.